# Changing the scope of 'this' using bind prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this, bind

I am using bind to change the scope of 'this' so that I am able to reference  my generateContent function using 'this', from within my click function. Unfortunately this means that this.id no longer works as the scope of 'this' has changed.

What is the best way to grab the id of the clicked button, in this case:

```
function help( doc ) {

    buttons: function() {

        $('.add-btn').click( function() {

        this.generateContent( this.id ) );

        }.bind(this));

    },

    generateContent: function ( id ){

    }

}

// This function binds a function to an object's scope.
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
    var _function = this;
    return function() {
        return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tag jQuery but your code quacks like jQuery so I'm assuming jQuery.

jQuery provides [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/):

```
$('.add-btn').click( function(e) {
     this.generateContent( e.currentTarget.id ) ;
}.bind(this));
```

Btw `Function.prototype.bind` exists natively, you don't want to overwrite it in the cases where the native version is available. jQuery also provides `$.proxy`, so you don't need it in any case.

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HeT5S/)

Comment: Thank you very much :) That was exactly what I wanted to know. Have added Jquery tag.